# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to use the [d3-gauge](https://github.com/thlorenz/d3-gauge) plugin from a very basic node.js/express server. I have generated the default directory and file tree with express and copied the files from the 'example' directory where the should be:

```
.
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── style.css
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
└── views
    ├── error.jade
    ├── index.jade
    └── layout.jade
```

The changes I have made are these:

I copied 'main.js' under 'javascripts' as 'gauge-main.js'.

I copied    'small.css', 'simple.css', 'grayscale.css', 'index.css' under    'stylesheets' as 'gauge-small.css', 'gauge-simple.css',    'gauge-grayscale.css', 'gauge-index.css' respectively.

I modified 'index.jade':

```
extends layout

block head
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        title Index
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css', type='text/css', media='screen', charset='utf-8')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/gauge-index.css', type='text/css', media='screen', charset='utf-8')
block body
        script(src='/javascripts/gauge-main.js', type='text/javascript', charset='utf-8')
```

and 'layout.jade':

```
doctype html
html
  head
    block head
  body
    block body
```

to correspond with the example.

When the app is run (with 'npm start') it works, and when I access the page no 404 is produced. All the '*.css' files and the 'gauge-main.js' are linked correctly.

The problem is that nothing is displayed in the browser. When I 'inspect' the page I can see there is a problem with 'gauge-main.js' The error says 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined'. This has to do with the fact that JavaScript in the browser does not support require. After some research I found that the correct way to resolve this is with an extension called 'browserify'. The issue here is that I think the author of the 'd3-gauge' plugin does not intend it to be used this way (with 'browserify' that is). When I 'inspect' the [page](http://thlorenz.github.io/d3-gauge/) from the author's site, I find no trace of 'browserify'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `package.json`, the demo is run by `beefy`. [Beefy](https://github.com/chrisdickinson/beefy) is designed to work with `browserify` which resolves `require`.

Comment: So, should I install beefy with 'npm install beefy'? Also, which 'package.json'? I cannot find any reference to 'beefy'.

Comment: beefy is ok for development, but when you deploy you will need to browserify your source code, here gauge-main.js

Comment: [package.json](https://github.com/thlorenz/d3-gauge/blob/master/package.json), take a look at `scripts` property, this is where `npm run demo` starts.

Comment: Could you possibly point me to any resources or guides for 'browserify'?